# Python: Can I write to a file without loading its contents in RAM?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

Got a big data-set that I want to shuffle. The entire set won't fit into RAM so it would be good if I could open several files (e.g. hdf5, numpy) simultaneously, loop through my data chronologically and randomly assign each data-point to one of the piles (then afterwards shuffle each pile).

I'm really inexperienced with working with data in python so I'm not sure if it's possible to write to files without holding the rest of its contents in RAM (been using np.save and savez with little success).

Is this possible and in h5py or numpy and, if so, how could I do it?

Comment: @desertnaut shuffling huge data-sets has nothing to do with machine learning?

Comment: read/write line ?

Comment: Tags are about the *content* of the question, and not its *context*; put it like that, ML has indeed nothing to do with "shuffling huge datasets". The tag would be appropriate here if this shuffling had something to do with, say, fitting your model - but this is not the case here.

Comment: Tags are, in part, used to attract people who are experienced in the area. As I alluded to, the vast majority of people interested in shuffling huge data-sets will, like me, be doing so in order to help improve a model's performance. I therefore included the tag as people experienced in machine learning are likely to have come across this problem and solved it.

It's clearly not a ridiculous tag so maybe hold back next time you want to fire off a snarky comment.

Comment: You can use Dask arrays to chunk your data https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-creation.html

Comment: An expert in machine learning will not necessarily know the details of a specific file format or the peculiarities of the available implementations for importing or exporting data using it. An expert for this file format on the other hand... Any reason you don't use a proper database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memmory mapped files will allow for what you want. They create a numpy array which leaves the data on disk, only loading data as needed.  The complete manual page is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).  However, the easiest way to use them is by passing the argument `mmap_mode=r+` or `mmap_mode=w+` in the call to `np.load` leaves the file on disk (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)).

I'd suggest using advanced indexing.  If you have data in a one dimensional array `arr`, you can index it using a list.  So `arr[ [0,3,5]]` will give you the 0th, 3rd, and 5th elements of `arr`.  That will make selecting the shuffled versions much easier.  Since this will overwrite the data you'll need to open the files on disk read only, and create copies (using `mmap_mode=w+`) to put the shuffled data in.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, I'll look into mmap and advanced indexing! :)