# How do I write a file in python without loading it into memory?

Tags: python, file, memory

My intuition was that writing a file line by line as possible in python, in the same way, that reading it is. I was wrong. Consider the following code.

```
with open("source_file.csv","r") as source, open("output_file.csv","w") as dest:
    while 1:
        buf = source.read(16*1024)
        if not buf:
                break
        dest.write(buf)
```

I observed how the output file is written via a `$ tail -f output_file.csv.` Data is displayed as it is being written. I interrupted the python script and noticed that none of that data was **written on disk**.

Here's my understanding of this so far :

- The `read` operation is indeed done line-by-line here **without loading it into memory**. The `write` operation, on the other hand, is loaded line-by-line **into memory**, before it is serialized and written on disk.
  I thought data could be written on disk chunk-by-chunk, to be memory efficient. Otherwise, any big file could not be copied (memory will eventually be insufficient), which is (Probably) what happens [in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955283/python-can-i-write-to-a-file-without-loading-its-contents-in-ram).
  My questions :
- Is my analysis correct? If not, I would like additional information.
- How do we write chunk-by-chunk **on disk**?

Comment: have you tried flushing the output buffer? My guess is that you will see nothing until the output buffer overflows, and then you will see 32K characters.

Comment: Swap the `while`and `with` lines. What you have is an infinite loop of re-writing the output file with the first 16K characters of the input file.